# UITableView - reusing cells while in editing mode

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm finding that if you set a table view into editing mode, upon scrolling the table after deleting a row the cell edit control (the red minus sign on the left) is in a random state (turned vertical or horizontal) on the rest of the cells as you scroll the table. Presumably because I'm reusing cells like this:

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

How can I force the edit control to be in the correct state for each cell? It should always be in the default horizontal state unless I tap it to delete a cell.

EDIT: Here's the cell code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"WhateverIdentifier";
    MyCell *cell = nil;

    //This IF statement fixes the problem, but then I'm not reusing the cells
    if (!tableView.isEditing) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    //customize cell

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more details about your code?

Comment: Posted an update to the question.

Comment: Does the MyCell* class have any custom things?

Comment: An image and a text label.

Comment: Any solution? I'm seeing the same thing in two separate projects

Answer (score 7):

Are you calling `[super prepareForReuse]` in the method `prepareForReuse` of your custom cell?

That resolved my problem.

Comment: AGGGGHHHHHHHHH I've spent a fortnight looking at this!!!!!! Thanks for the quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked in a UITableView I had handy, and I don't see that problem. I'm using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: as you are (without the if statement, of course). Are you doing something special with swiping, or deleting multiple rows or something?

(I'd make this a comment but can't yet. I'll delete it once you've resolved your problem.)